# Xcode build fails and repetitive requires command line developer tools install

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, command-line-tool, xcode-command-line-tools

I have updated Xcode to Version 13.4.1 (13F100),
Then tried to run a flutter project

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            2.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-06-11 12:51:51.546 xcodebuild[45221:416597] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-11 12:51:51.547 xcodebuild[45221:416597] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-06-11 12:51:51.625 xcodebuild[45221:416597] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension (null): (null)
    2022-06-11 12:51:51.628 xcodebuild[45221:416597] [MT] DVTPlugInExtensionFaulting: Failed to fire fault for extension (null): (null)
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/l6/zr2yb4p1787b1cbhjdn2ltvr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.tQVcwl/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirmZJ1FK/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    error: failed to read asset tags: The command `(cd /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios && /usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets)` exited with status 72. The command's standard error was:
    actool: error: Failed to locate 'actool'.
    xcode-select: Failed to locate 'actool', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
     (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/l6/zr2yb4p1787b1cbhjdn2ltvr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.tQVcwl/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirmZJ1FK/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): failed to read asset tags: The command `(cd /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios && /usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets)` exited with status 72. The command's standard error was:

actool: error: Failed to locate 'actool'.
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'actool', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
Exited
```

with an alert

> The "actool" command requires the command line developer tools. Would
> you like to install the tools now?

[image]
And if I run it from Xcode it gives me this error:

```
Showing All Messages
failed to read asset tags: The command `(cd /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios && /usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Volumes/Code/Git/svg/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets)` exited with status 72. The command's standard error was:

actool: error: Failed to locate 'actool'.
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'actool', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

**This repetitively occurs even if I press the "Install" button.**

Answer (score 9):

Same issue here, but with git instead of `actool`. Another coworker just also got this but with `clang`... what is going on over at apple?

What just fixed mine was actually opening up xcode and having it run its installer there instead of allowing the automatic pop-up to continue to "install" and then ask again in a few minutes.

Comment: Same for me. Opening up Xcode and having it run its installer solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick for me as well.